# Insert Where Not Exists-Without Primary Key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, overwrite

I have 3 tables: dentists, groups, and groupdentlink. Many dentists link to many groups through the groupdentlink table.

So I'm trying to make a query where it will insert rows into groupdentlink (linking all dentists in the state with all the groups in the state) but only if those rows don't already exist. In a nutshell I want to add new rows without overwriting existing ones or duplicating them.

So the *intent* of the query is something like:

```
INSERT INTO groupdentlink (f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id)
VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$groupid', '$scheduleid')
WHERE NOT EXISTS ('$_POST[id]', '$groupid')
```

And I don't have any primary keys in the groupdentlink table.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## If you really want to write your own (working) query..

---

```
INSERT INTO groupdentlink (
  f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id
) SELECT 
    '$_POST[id]'  f_dent_id, 
    '$groupid'    f_group_id,
    '$scheduleid' f_schedule_id
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM `groupdentlink`
  WHERE 
    f_dent_id = '$_POST[id]' AND f_group_id = '$groupid'
  LIMIT 1 -- tells mysql to stop searching after first match
)
```

## ... but MySQL can handle all this for you!

---

You don't need primary keys to make MySQL handle this for you, you should add a `UNIQUE` key constraint on the combined set of the two columns.

Query to add the unique key `dent_group_uniq_key` to `groupdentlink`.

```
ALTER TABLE groupdentlink ADD UNIQUE KEY `dent_group_uniq_key` (
  f_dent_id, f_group_id
);
```

Then use `INSERT IGNORE` on your query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO groupdentlink (
  f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id
) VALUES (
  '$_POST[id]', '$groupid', '$scheduleid'
)
```

`INSERT IGNORE` will try to insert a row to your table, if it fails due to a key constraint it will act like nothing happen.

Comment: OK, but you won't get an error if it fails for different reasons, like a foreign key constraint violation.

Comment: @greyfairer It will only "IGNORE" if the insert fails due to a duplicate key, foreign key constraints still apply.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using the second method: Unique key from combined columns since it seems simpler to me.

Comment: You don't need the `LIMIT 1` in the subquery, MySQL automatically stops after a single row is found in a EXISTS clause

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO groupdentlink (f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id)
SELECT '$_POST[id]', '$groupid', '$scheduleid' FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  select * from groupdentlink 
  where f_dent_id='$_POST[id]'
  and f_group_id='$groupid'
)
```

And I think you can create a composite primary key on the combination (f_dent_id, f_group_id) just to make sure.

Comment: As a tip, use `1` instead of `*` on your `exists` statements so that you're not trying to pull back a large column set in memory. Speeds up the query a bit (can have a big impact the larger the query gets, and depends on the engine).

Comment: @Eric, that is not the case. See the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html): Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT * , but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.

Comment: Ah, MySQL doesn't do that--older versions of SQL Server used to (don't know if they still do), and that's where all my work is done in. I use it as a best practice.

Comment: Can't find any errant parentheses, commas, quote marks yet. Any ideas? The code you posted looks good? Mysql server version is 5.1.60.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it! You can use a select statement to feed an insert statement. Just do this:

```
INSERT INTO groupdentlink (f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id)
SELECT '$_POST[id]', '$groupid', '$scheduleid'
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
    select 
        1 
    from 
        groupdentlink 
    where 
        f_dent_id = $_POST[id] 
        and f_group_id = '$groupid'
    )
```

Comment: hmm. Here's my query: "INSERT INTO groupdentlink (f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id)
 SELECT '$_POST[id]', '$rowv[id]', '$row[f_sched_id]'
 WHERE
 NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM groupdentlink 
        WHERE f_dent_id = '$_POST[id]' 
        AND f_group_id = '$groupid'"

...and I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: You need the closing paren on the exists clause.

Comment: What's the syntax error that you're getting, or is it not specific?

Comment: Huh...can you just do the select statement that's within the `not exists` clause?

Comment: Here's my full query: "INSERT INTO groupdentlink (f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id)
        VALUES ('$_POST[memberid]', '$rowv[id]', '$rowv[f_sched_id]')
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       select * FROM groupdentlink
       where f_dent_id = '$_POST[memberid]'
       and f_group_id = '$rowv[id]'
      )"

Comment: Sorry, I had changed some of the values earlier to make it easier to explain but this is the actual query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO groupdentlink (f_dent_id, f_group_id, f_schedule_id)
VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$groupid', '$scheduleid')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  select * from groupdentlink 
  where f_dent_id='$_POST[id]'
  and f_group_id='$groupid'
)
```

And I think you can create a composite primary key on the combination (f_dent_id, f_group_id).