# How to avoid inserting two same records twice when double-clicking the submit button?

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, double-submit-prevention, double-submit-problem

I have a popup window where there are two onclick methods as "Submit" and "Discard".

When I click **submit** twice it insert two records that means duplicate record.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Client-Solution: disable the button after the first click...

Comment: @AleksandrM: I disagree on the Struts2 tag removal, the question is about preventing double form submission, and Struts2 has even *two* inbuilt ways to do that :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Beside bunch of tags there are no signs that OP actually uses S2. But ok... we'll see.

Comment: Isn't that the reason tags are for ? :| But ok, BHAGATH SHIVARAM you should edit your question and **specify clearly in the text if you are using Struts2.** @RomanC, the Q&A you linked is language agnostic and therefore doesn't make this a duplicate. I don't see any Struts2 solution in that Q&A, do you ?

Answer (score 7):

Preventing a double-submit is a common problem.

Even though there are many solutions to it, since you've tagged it [struts2](/questions/tagged/struts2), there are two ways provided out-of-the-box by the framework to handle double-submit:

- ### The [Token Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/docs/token-interceptor.html)

  It returns an `invalid.token` result that can, for example, be mapped to an error:

  > **Ensures that only one request per token is processed. This interceptor can make sure that back buttons and double clicks don't cause un-intended side affects.** For example, **you can use this to prevent careless users who might double click on a "checkout" button at an online store**. This interceptor uses a fairly primitive technique for when an invalid token is found: it returns the result `invalid.token`, which can be mapped in your action configuration. A more complex implementation, TokenSessionStoreInterceptor, can provide much better logic for when invalid tokens are found.
  >
  > **Note**: To set a token in your form, you should use the `token tag`. This tag is required and must be used in the forms that submit to actions protected by this interceptor. Any request that does not provide a token (using the token tag) will be processed as a request with an invalid token.
- ### The [Token Session Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/docs/token-session-interceptor.html)

  It builds off the Token Interceptor, but with a more advanced and user-friendly behaviour, that **is exactly what you need**: in case of a double form submit, it renders the result of the first, valid request, while silently swallowing the second (and the subsequent) request(s):

  > This interceptor builds off of the TokenInterceptor, providing advanced logic for handling invalid tokens. Unlike the normal token interceptor, this interceptor will attempt to provide intelligent fail-over in the event of multiple requests using the same session. That is, **it will block subsequent requests until the first request is complete, and then instead of returning the `invalid.token` code, it will attempt to display the same response that the original, valid action invocation would have displayed if no multiple requests were submitted in the first place.**

#### IMPORTANT !

It is worth noting that, [exactly like for the Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341208/1654265), a server-side solution like this should be **mandatory**, while a client-side solution like disabling the submit button with Javascript alone is not enough. 
**What if the user re-enables the button with Firebug ? What if he/she forges a request with Javascript ? If I'm on my Bank site and try to send a request twice (eg. a cash transfer), it is crucial that it gets processed only once.**

Then go with the server-side solution, and *if you really want*, add a client-side protection too... keeping in mind that you need to carefully check every possible case, to not end up in your page with a disabled button after a request is over (especially with [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), that you tagged) due to an unforeseen result.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the user from double clicking on the client side as suggested by @Stefan, but if you're looking for a way on preventing it from the backend/mysql
check the answer from

[Insert Where Not Exists-Without Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525333/insert-where-not-exists-without-primary-key)